# (How) Can I make a newsfeed out of this?

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

My website uses a table for wallposts ("users_wall") and one for followers ("users_follow").
The wallposts table looks like this (more or less):

```
ID    NAME    USER_ID (the id of the wall it's posted on)   CONTENT
1     James     3                                             Hi!
2     Jim       3                                             Hey there!
```

And the followers/following table looks like this:

```
ID   HEFOLLOWS    THISGUY
1     James         Jim
2     Jim           James
```

How can I make a working <strike>table</strike> feed out of this? I currently have a feed, but I found no way of sorting it by the id of the posts, rather than the person posting. Mine would look like:

```
James: Hey (15th)
James: Hi! (13th)

Jim:   Hi! (14th)
```

When I want it to be:

```
James: Hey (15th)
Jim:   Hi! (14th)
James: Hi! (13th)
```

So how could I do this? Please explain rather than sending me to a general mysql/php learning website.

Thank you :)

EDIT: This is a **basic version** of how I make the news feed:

```
<?php
$getfollowing = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users_follow WHERE hefollows = '$username'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getfollowing)){
  $followername = $row['thisguy'];
  $getposts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users_wall WHERE name = '$followername' SORT BY id DESC");
  while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($getposts){
    $date = $rows['date']
    (...)
  ?>
  <div class="share">
    <?php echo($nameofposter); ?>
    <br />
    <?php echo($share_content); ?> ( <?php echo($date); ?> )
  </div>
  <?php
  }
  ?>
```

This will result in:

```
<div class="share">
  James
  <br />
  Hey (15th)
</div>

<div class="share">
  James
  <br />
  Hi! (13th)
</div>

<div class="share">
  Jim
  <br />
  Hi! (14th)
</div>
```

Because James is first in the database, and it's sorted by the follower/following instead of ID of share.

Comment: How do you get `14th`, `13th `?

Comment: What SQL command do you use to the get the feed?

Comment: Like John above mentioned, you need a date in the message table (when was it posted?). Then use a `JOIN` on the 2 tables and order on `date`.

Comment: sorting by post ID will give order inserted into table

Comment: It's odd that you are getting them sorted by poster rather than by ID - I'm assuming ID is a primary key and most (all?) SQL-driven database engines will return results in order of the primary key unless you supply an explicit `ORDER BY` to tell it other wise. But you can still explicitly `ORDER BY id` if it's causing a problem. It does seem like you should have a specific column for recording the date/time of the post though - as a general rule the primary key of a table should be irrelevant to the actual data it pertains to, it's just an identifier.

Comment: No they wont auto sort by ID if your using mysql_* which is depreciated. (try deleting mid result entry and then insert a new one) Hit that problem very early on when learning. p.s. ORDER BY post_table.ID

Comment: @Waygood I don't think the driver you're using to communicate with the DB is relevant because it should be internal to the DB (although I could be wrong about that, but I don't think I am). Unless you tell it otherwise, the DB would return the results in the natural order in which they are stored, which unless your table is either ridiculously large or very badly designed would be in the order in which they were inserted, and that normally means they would be ordered by the primary key in ascending order.

Comment: As I stated, if you delete rows, the space is reused by the next insert and not just added to the end, otherwise you'd run out of space. This knowledge is from experience, hence the mysql_* comment as I dont work on systems using PDO etc..

Comment: I do have dates. The sample tables were just to explain. I use a "while()" and it repeats for each share, or wall post.The current way I do it is a while for each follower, and inside the while, a new one for each share by the follow. Which I know isn't a good way, but I'm merely a beginner with mysql.

Comment: And I get them by date--id I mean, by 'SORT BY id DESC' - pretty simple. The ID isn't replaced when a share is deleted, the ID just get's a higher value than the last.

Comment: I edited the post so you can see how I make the feed.

Answer (score 1):

You must have a date field, or use a timestamp to organize posts chronologically.

[update]
Ahhhh I think the problem is then that you are trying to iterate something with while loops when it should be done with a join statement. I know you really didn't want someone to link you to a generic PHP page, but this is a mysql page and it is what you need.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

When you try to use this, come back with what you made and if you still have problems I'll try to help troubleshoot.

Comment: Wont an autoincrement field do the same? as it increases with each insert? so we know the order they were inserted but just not the time it was done.

Comment: Sure if you want whenever something gets edited to go right to the top of the feed.

Comment: So editing/updating creates a new record? Maybe I grant you? but I was going by the supplied info and it took a while for OP to state they were already using it

Comment: See the example I have. It's not about that kind of sorting, it's the way that I do it, so that it is sorted by the username. On their profiles or walls, they are perfectly sorted.

Comment: I think you understand, and thank you. I will look into that.

Comment: Thank you so much! This has been bugging me for ages, but knowing about joining tables was something that opened lots of oppertunities, including the wall to work. For future refrence, please link to this video, it was the best: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6BfofgkrI3Y